# Updating a variable using its current value in Python

Tags: python

I am writing a program to produce an image of the Mandelbrot set. The set requires iterating through the formula: z = z_{n-1}^2 + C. The (n-1) refers to the previous value of z in the loop. In my program I have written

```
z_new = (self.z)**2.0 + c_number
self.z = z_new
```

within a loop.

Is there a better way in python to update a value using its current value? I'm not sure the `+=` operator would work here, since the formula requires squaring the current value before adding the complex number, C.

Comment: Why do you think this is not a good way?

Comment: You can leave out the extra variable: `self.z = (self.z)**2 + c_number`. Otherwise, what is there to improve? It's perfectly clear as it is.

Comment: If you _wanted_ you could do `self.z *= self.z` `self.z += c_number`, but it's no improvement really.

Comment: I thought that using the same variable name might lead to unexpected behaviour (e.g. using the wrong value on the RHS of the = sign), but if this line works as expected, then it is ever so slightly more succinct. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may have mis-interpreted @Lev_Levitsky's comment. If you wanted it on one line then they suggested:

```py
self.z = self.z**2 + c_number
```

is equivalent to what you've got written. You don't really need the temporary variable `z_new` since in the "one-liner" the previous value of `self.z` is used when setting the next value.

Answer (score 0):

the simplified version should be:

```py
self.z = (self.z)**2.0 + c_number
```